# Filter many-many relationship result (flask sqlalchemy)

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a basic many to many relationship as below,

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    user_favs  = relationship('Loop', secondary='active_association')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {}>'.format(self.username)


class Loop(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    creation_date = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    genre = db.Column(db.String())
    author = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))


class Active_Association(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'active_association'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    loop_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('loop.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean(), default=False)
```

I am adding user_favs like so:

```
loop = Loop.query.filter_by(id = request.form.get('loop')).first()
user = User.query.filter_by(id = request.form.get('user')).first()

user.user_favs.append(loop)
db.session.commit()
```

Later I am retrieving all user_favs like so:

```
user = User.query.filter_by(id = current_user.id).first()

loops = user.user_favs
```

This gives me an array containing all user_favs but I am struggling to a way to filter it by genre.

I could loop over it but that doesn't seem like the proper solution.

I attempted

```
user = User.query.filter_by(id = current_user.id).first()

loops = user.active_loops

filter(loops.genre == 'jazz')
```

But this gives me an AttributeError: 'AppenderQuery' object has no attribute 'genre'

Perhaps I have set my whole relationship up wrong and should be able to just filter it directly if set up correctly? This is my first many - many relationship so I may also be on the wrong track with:

```
active = db.Column(db.Boolean(), default=False)
```

Which was intended for some other functionality but I do not know how to address that either.

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `lazy='dynamic'` which will give you a BaseQuery for the relationship itself. Dynamic just means the join type between the two models.

```py
class Loop(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    creation_date = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    genre = db.Column(db.String())
    author = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    # will be .authors from Loop.authors
    authors = db.relationship(
        'User', 
        secondary=Active_Association, 
        backref=db.backref('loops'), # will be .loops on User
        lazy='dynamic'
    )
```

In essence, it is a query in a query for maximum flexibility.

```py
# gets the user
user = User.query.filter_by(id = current_user.id).first()

# this will return a collection of loops
loops = user.loops.filter_by(genre='jazz')
```

I have been trying to manage this in one query without the second query but need to sit down to run through it because my joining skillz are a bit rusty with SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Old post of mine but still very useful! I think being able to .filter_by() after user.loops was still an unknown approach!